# how to iterate json to table in row wise

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

Below I have a JSON structure to create a group of values for students. In order to make the whole thing work, I need to use jQuery to get the exact values of specific students (which will be done in an HTML file).

How would I do this?

```
[{
"Class": "A",
"as_of": "12/31/2020",
"student": [
    {
        "raji": {
            "eng": "35",
            "soc": "40",
            "sci": "39"
        }
    },
    {
        "akg": {
            "eng": "17",
            "soc": "40",
            "sci": "24"
        }
    }
]
}]
```

The table needs to be structured like the one below:

```
|sub | raji | akg|
|eng |35    | 17 |
|soc |40    | 40 |
|sci |39    | 24 |
```

Comment: Will there be only two columns (`raji` and `akg`) always or is it a variable?

Comment: total 30 students, raji and akg are student names

Comment: please show your attempt .

Comment: you're using data values as your key/property names, making it difficult to parse into anything usable, like a table.  Can you change the format of the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your data format is inconsistent with the description. Your question doesn't cover many important facts such as are the courses fixed or there might be more courses than three? Also, the `student` array contains an object that contains another object! Why there is such a bad design? Will there be more students under one object of the `student` array?

It would be much better if you could organize the data something like this:

```
[{
  "Class": "A",
  "as_of": "12/31/2020",
  "student": {
    "raji": {
      "eng": "35",
      "soc": "40",
      "sci": "39"
    },
    "akg": {
      "eng": "17",
      "soc": "40",
      "sci": "24"
    }
  }
}]
```

This way you could avoid unnecessary nesting. However, I have managed a way to sort this out. There are many ways to derive the result you asked for based on the data you have provided and here is my approach.

First, I cleaned up your data and convert those data into a 2d object of `marks[student][subject]` format so that we can easily access to that info during table creation.

```
let classes = [{
  "Class": "A",
  "as_of": "12/31/2020",
  "student": [{
      "raji": {
        "eng": "35",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "39"
      }
    },
    {
      "akg": {
        "eng": "17",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "24"
      }
    }
  ]
}]



classes.forEach((item) => {

  let students = item.student;
  let marks = {}

  students.forEach((student) => {
    let student_names = Object.keys(student);

    student_names.forEach((name) => {

      if (marks[name] == undefined) {
        marks[name] = {}
      }

      let results = student[name];
      let subjects = Object.keys(results)

      subjects.forEach((subject) => {
        marks[name][subject] = results[subject]
      })

    })
  });

  console.log(marks)

});
```

Now the marks object contains the mark of each student by subject. Something like this:-

```
{
  "raji": {
    "eng": "35",
    "soc": "40",
    "sci": "39"
  },
  "akg": {
    "eng": "17",
    "soc": "40",
    "sci": "24"
  }
}
```

Now, the final part is to create a table. There are lots of ways of doing this. You can use jQuery for this or just HTML DOM but I used a mixed version to speed up things. I will provide another way of doing this with JavaScript `createElement` in the future. But for now, this will work as well. So here is the final code.

```js
let classes = [{
  "Class": "A",
  "as_of": "12/31/2020",
  "student": [{
      "raji": {
        "eng": "35",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "39"
      }
    },
    {
      "akg": {
        "eng": "17",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "24"
      }
    }
  ]
}]



classes.forEach((item) => {

  let students = item.student;
  let marks = {}

  students.forEach((student) => {
    let student_names = Object.keys(student);

    student_names.forEach((name) => {

      if (marks[name] == undefined) {
        marks[name] = {}
      }

      let results = student[name];
      let subjects = Object.keys(results)

      subjects.forEach((subject) => {
        marks[name][subject] = results[subject]
      })

    })
  });


  let all_students = Object.keys(marks);
  let all_subjects = [...new Set(all_students.map(std => Object.keys(marks[std])).flat())]


  let theads = all_students.map((studnet) => {
    return `<th>${studnet}</th>`;
  })

  let tableHeader = `<thead><tr><th>Sub</th>${theads.join("")}</tr></thead>`;

  let tbodies = []

  all_subjects.forEach((subject) => {
    let mark_td = all_students.map(student => `<td>${marks[student][subject]}</td>`)
    tbodies.push(`<tr><td>${subject}</td>${mark_td.join("")}</tr>`)
  })

  let tableBody = `<tbody>${tbodies.join("")}</tbody>`


  let table = `<table>${tableHeader}${tableBody}</table>`;


  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += table

})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: The student array *should be* an array; it's not "bad design".  The bad design is that there's no `"name":"raji"` property.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense as well.

Comment: hi @lftieap,  thanks for the detailed workout and for explaining the concept clearly, this is worked as expected. i got all the details i need develop my students project

Comment: @lftieap, i tried a approach and got the data in column wise, so not ready to show because it may confuse so only i haven't added what i tried

Comment: @Iftieaq, i have one more doubt, with this code how to interchange the first column value from another json? kind of 
label.json holding 
`{"subjectLabels": {
        "eng": "english",
        "sci": "environment science",
        "soc": "History & Geo",
    }}`

Comment: @lftieaq, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319374/how-to-replace-the-value-by-comparing-two-json-and-to-update-in-the-created-tabl