# how to replace the value by comparing two json and to update in the created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ecmascript-6

I have two json files, holding values like the below,
Json 1:

```
let classes = [{
  "Class": "A",
  "as_of": "12/31/2020",
  "student": [{
      "raji": {
        "eng": "35",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "39"
      }
    },
    {
      "akg": {
        "eng": "17",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "24"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

json 2:

```
let subjectDetails = [{
 "subjectLabels": {
   "eng": "english",
   "sci": "environment science",
   "soc": "History & Geo"
 }
}]
```

with this json 1 Value i can able to create the table refer : [how to iterate json to table in row wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261905/how-to-iterate-json-to-table-in-row-wise) , now i have to replace the value of 'eng' in table as 'english' by getting value from Json2. also i have more subjects to include in table so need a dynamic key reference solution. can anyone help me to resolve this

Comment: They're not JSON files. Those are both JavaScript files with JS Objects.

Comment: i written here as js objects, i think this enough to get the result so only added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will have to write a function that will iterate the `subjectDetails` array and find the subject name based on a label.

```
let subjectDetails = [{
  "subjectLabels": {
    "eng": "english",
    "sci": "environment science",
    "soc": "History & Geo"
  }
}]

const getSubjectName = (label) => {
  let name = label;
  
  subjectDetails.forEach(details => {
     if(details.subjectLabels.hasOwnProperty(label)){
       name = details.subjectLabels[label]
     }
  })

  return name
}

console.log(getSubjectName("eng"))
//OUTPUT: english
```

The `getSubjectName` will return the name of the subject if exists otherwise the default label.

The second part is already answered on the referenced answer. All you have to do is to update the label in place.

```js
let classes = [{
  "Class": "A",
  "as_of": "12/31/2020",
  "student": [{
      "raji": {
        "eng": "35",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "39"
      }
    },
    {
      "akg": {
        "eng": "17",
        "soc": "40",
        "sci": "24"
      }
    }
  ]
}]


let subjectDetails = [{
  "subjectLabels": {
    "eng": "english",
    "sci": "environment science",
    "soc": "History & Geo"
  }
}]

const getSubjectName = (label) => {
  let name = label;
  
  subjectDetails.forEach(details => {
     if(details.subjectLabels.hasOwnProperty(label)){
       name = details.subjectLabels[label]
     }
  })

  return name
}

classes.forEach((item) => {

  let students = item.student;
  let marks = {}

  students.forEach((student) => {
    let student_names = Object.keys(student);

    student_names.forEach((name) => {

      if (marks[name] == undefined) {
        marks[name] = {}
      }

      let results = student[name];
      let subjects = Object.keys(results)

      subjects.forEach((subject) => {
        marks[name][subject] = results[subject]
      })

    })
  });


  let all_students = Object.keys(marks);
  let all_subjects = [...new Set(all_students.map(std => Object.keys(marks[std])).flat())]


  let theads = all_students.map((studnet) => {
    return `<th>${studnet}</th>`;
  })

  let tableHeader = `<thead><tr><th>Sub</th>${theads.join("")}</tr></thead>`;

  let tbodies = []

  all_subjects.forEach((subject) => {
    let sub_label = getSubjectName(subject)
    let mark_td = all_students.map(student => `<td>${marks[student][subject]}</td>`)
    tbodies.push(`<tr><td>${sub_label}</td>${mark_td.join("")}</tr>`)
  })

  let tableBody = `<tbody>${tbodies.join("")}</tbody>`


  let table = `<table>${tableHeader}${tableBody}</table>`;


  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += table

})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @lftieaq, this is worked as expected, i did the iteration of second array but i was stopped in comparing and getting the value. if i get the subjectdetails then i cant able to get the marks. that's the problem i faced